# video fallback using object tag doesn't work with appendChild

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-video, flash

I've got a video player application that uses a variant of [video For everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody). With a HTML5 `<video>` tag enclosing a `<object>` tag for flash falback on internet exploder. It all works well when I do this statically, however when the video elements are built using javascript, it seems that IE9 doesn't like this.

If i use static code like this it works:

```
<video id="video" width="360" height="240>
<source type="video/ogg" src="content/mov1.ogv"></source>
<source type="video/mp4" src="content/mov1.mp4"></source>
<object data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="384" width="512">
<param name="movie" value="player.swf" >
<param value="autostart=true&amp;file=/mov1.mp4" name="flashvars">
</object>
</video>
```

but when I use a javascript function to build the video player as below, it doesn't.

```
function makeV4EPlayer(mp4URL, ogvURL, movieWidth, movieHeight, displayname){
    //create the video element and set its attributes
    var videoObject= document.createElement('video');
    videoObject.setAttribute("id", "video");        
    videoObject.setAttribute("width", movieWidth);
    videoObject.setAttribute("height", movieHeight);

    //add mp4 source
    var mp4Src=document.createElement('source');
    mp4Src.setAttribute("src", mp4URL);
    mp4Src.setAttribute("type","video/mp4");
    videoObject.appendChild(mp4Src);

    //add ogv source
    var oggSrc=document.createElement('source');
    oggSrc.setAttribute("src", ogvURL);
    oggSrc.setAttribute("type","video/ogg");
    videoObject.appendChild(oggSrc);

    //add object with flash player      
    var flashObject=document.createElement('object');
    flashObject.setAttribute("width", movieWidth);
    flashObject.setAttribute("height", movieHeight);
    flashObject.setAttribute("type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
    flashObject.setAttribute("data","swf/player.swf");
    var params1 = document.createElement('param');
    params1.setAttribute("name", "movie");
    params1.setAttribute("value","swf/player.swf");
    var params2=document.createElement('param');
    params2.setAttribute("name","flashvars");
    params2.setAttribute("value",'autostart=true' + '&file=/' + mp4URL);
    flashObject.appendChild(params1);
    flashObject.appendChild(params2);
    videoObject.appendChild(flashObject);

    return videoObject;
}
```

The Javascript builds the `<video>` tag just fine, and populates it with all the stuff, it's just that IE won't play it. Of course it works happily on every other browser in the universe.

When I use the IE9 developer tools to inspect the pages I note that in the static version it sees the video tag and the object tag as being siblings - that is the object isn't inside the video tag, but in the javascript version the object is nested inside the video tag. That I believe is the nub of the problem.

I don't think it's relevant, but I'm using the JW Player as my fallback flash player.

Answer (score 0):

The *IE* doesn't support the *ogg* format (also see the [browser compatibility page](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements#Browser_compatibility)), the other brwoser do.

Maybe the MP4 URL is not correct or the file broken?

=== UPDATE ===

In the following line you are using `imagesrc` which is not defined before:

```
params2.setAttribute("value",'autostart=true' + imagesrc + '&file=/' + mp4URL);
```

You should initialze it before.

=== UDPATE ===

If the `object` tag shouldn't be in the `video` tag you have to make changes, because you can only return one element. E.g. put both in a wrapper element:

```
function makeV4EPlayer(mp4URL, ogvURL, movieWidth, movieHeight, displayname){
    // create a wrapper
    var videoWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    videoWrapper.style.width = movieWidth+'px';
    videoWrapper.style.height = movieHeight+'px';
    videoWrapper.style.padding = '0';
    videoWrapper.style.margin = '0';

    //create the video element and set its attributes
    var videoObject= document.createElement('video');
    videoObject.setAttribute("id", "video");        
    videoObject.setAttribute("width", movieWidth);
    videoObject.setAttribute("height", movieHeight);

    //add mp4 source
    var mp4Src=document.createElement('source');
    mp4Src.setAttribute("src", mp4URL);
    mp4Src.setAttribute("type","video/mp4");
    videoObject.appendChild(mp4Src);

    //add ogv source
    var oggSrc=document.createElement('source');
    oggSrc.setAttribute("src", ogvURL);
    oggSrc.setAttribute("type","video/ogg");
    videoObject.appendChild(oggSrc);

    // add video to wrapper
    videoWrapper.appendChild(videoObject);

    //add object with flash player      
    var flashObject=document.createElement('object');
    flashObject.setAttribute("width", movieWidth);
    flashObject.setAttribute("height", movieHeight);
    flashObject.setAttribute("type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
    flashObject.setAttribute("data","swf/player.swf");
    var params1 = document.createElement('param');
    params1.setAttribute("name", "movie");
    params1.setAttribute("value","swf/player.swf");
    var params2=document.createElement('param');
    params2.setAttribute("name","flashvars");
    params2.setAttribute("value",'autostart=true' + '&file=/' + mp4URL);
    flashObject.appendChild(params1);
    flashObject.appendChild(params2);

    // add flash player to wrapper
    videoWrapper.appendChild(flashObject);

    return videoWrapper;
}
```

You can also test with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xc5Vn/) (I've no IE9 so I can't do it for you).

Alternatively, you can create two functions, one for the video tag, the other for the object tag.

Comment: It does support .mp4, though, as of IE9. That's the whole point of multiple source tags.

Comment: That's not the issue. The point of video for everybody is that non supported browsers should fall through to the `<object>` tag. Which it does in the static version, but not where the `<video>` element has been built by the javascript.

Comment: Oops, that imagesrc is a typo, it is actually defined in the full code, I just summarised for the question and forgot to take it out. I've edited it now. It's not the ogv support that is causing the problem, I can take it out leaving just the mp4 source and still have the same result.

Comment: I didn't mean that the ogg file or the code are a problem, your code works. I think the mp4 file or the mp4 url is not correct. The onliest browser which supports mp4 is the IE so all test in the other browser are irrelevant (because they don't understand the mp4 format and use the ogg file).